# Running an extension less file as php

Tags: php, .htaccess, cgi, fastcgi

I was using .htaccess to run an extensionless file as PHP using

```
<Files thumbs>
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</Files>
```

but i changed my server to a CGI/FastCGI since then this is not working. I tried online and also here but couldn't find a solution .

Also i tried

```
<Files "thumbs">
   ForceType application/x-httpd-php
</Files>
```

Then the file is getting downloaded instead of executing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it fixed by making application/x-httpd-php it as application/x-httpd-php5

```
<Files thumbs>
   SetHandler application/x-httpd-php5
</Files>
```