# Treat an incomplete filename in a URL as PHP?

Tags: php, apache

I didn't write this web code. I just have to deploy it....

The `$WEBROOT` directory includes `index.php` and `login.php`, among others.

The automatic redirect URL from `index.php` (which successfully executes when just the domain URL is requested) is `http://$HOST.$DOMAIN/login?p=$VALUE` 
This returns the code `404`.

If I manually change the URL to `http://$HOST.$DOMAIN/login.php?p=$VALUE`

the login page successfully appears.

My first problem is I don't know what keywords to search for in the Apache documentation for this. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38943929/running-an-extension-less-file-as-php) seems close. But, my actual files have the `.php` extension. My problem is that I have to assume all of the URLs will just request `file` and not `file.php`.

How do I tell Apache to look for `file.php` before it returns a 404 for not finding `file`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a file named `.htaccess` with the following content inside the folder your `.php` files are in:

```
#turn on url rewriting 
RewriteEngine on

#remove the need for .php extention 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Comment: That did it! My only note is that I have access to httpd.conf and [Apache says that's a better place than .htaccess files](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html). So, this code went into the <Directory /> </Directory> block. Thanks!